# How to copy an array to a new array with dynamic name?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a complex data structure in Bash like this:

```
Test1_Name="test 1"
Test1_Files=(
  file01.txt
  file02.txt
)
Test2_Name="test 2"
Test2_Files=(
  file11.txt
  file12.txt
)
TestNames="Test1 Test2"
```

In my improved script, I would like read the files from disk. Each test resides in a directory.

So I have a Bash snippet reading directories and reading all the file names. The result is present in an array: `$Files[*]`.

How can I copy that array to an array prefixed with the test's name. Let's assume `$TestName` holds the test's name.

I know how to create a dynamically named array:

```
for $Name in $TestNames; do
  declare -a "${TestName}_Files"
done
```

Will create e.g. `Test1_Files` and `Test2_Files`. The variables are of type array, because I used `-a` in declare.

But how can I copy `$Files[*]` to `"${TestName}_Files"` in such a loop?

I tried this:

```
declare -a "${TestName}_Files"=${Files[*]}
```

But it gives an error that `=file01.txt` is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `newarray=( "${oldarray[@]}" )` to keep the array elements intact. `${oldarray[*]}` will involve word splitting, which will break at least with elements containing white space.

However, the obvious `declare -a "$name"=("${oldarray[@]}")` doesn't work, with the parenthesis quoted or not. One way to do it seems to be to use a name ref. This would copy the contents of `old` to `new`, where the name of `new` can be given dynamically:

```
#!/bin/bash
old=("abc" "white space")
name=new

declare -a "$name"        # declare the new array, make 'ref' point to it
declare -n ref="$name"    

ref=( "${old[@]}" )       # copy

#unset -n ref             # unset the nameref, if required
declare -p "$name"        # verify results
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `declare -p "$name"`?

Comment: @Paebbels, just to print out the new copy to verify the result is correct